# "Cannot read property addEventListener of null" when adding EventListener JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add an eventListener to a variable set to an element. 
The code is this:

```
var c = document.getElementById("some_element");
c.addEventListener("click", someFunction);
```

(BTW if it helps the element is a **button**.)

Comment: Btw when i use `var media = new MediaRecorder(stream);` and then add an event listener it works.

Comment: Sorry no it doesn't.

Comment: That means that (at least at the point of execution of that line) no element with that `id` exists in your page's DOM (or the part that is parsed until then).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems this code is getting execute before the dom is ready & at that point the element is available in DOM so it is throwing `null`

Try by adding the code neae closing end of body tag

```
<body>
 // rest of html elmeent
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("some_element");
c.addEventListener("click", someFunction);
</script>
</body>
```

Also you can put your code inside [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

```
window.onload = function(){
 var c = document.getElementById("some_element");
    c.addEventListener("click", someFunction);
}
```

Comment: I'd rather go with `DOMContentLoaded` than the `load` event. Why wait for images to be loaded?